# Unable to fix NullPointerException by Debugging Stacktrace

Tags: java, quicksort

I have debugged and try to figure out the cause from stacktrace but unable to find the reason of NullPointerException for this particular input. If I change the last input(marked in code) greater than 20, code executes successfully, but if its less than 20 then it throws exception.

```
package geeksforgeek.examples.sorting;

public class SinglyLinkedList { 

Node head;
Node current;
public void add(int data){
    if(head == null){
        head = new Node(data);
        current = head;
        return;
    }

    while(current.next != null)
        current = current.next;
    current.next = new Node(data);
}

public void print(Node node){
    current = node;
    while(this.current != null) {
        System.out.print(" "+current.data);
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

static  class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SinglyLinkedList quick = new SinglyLinkedList();
    quick.add(30);
    quick.add(3);
    quick.add(4);
    quick.add(20);
    quick.add(15);
    quick.add(55);
    quick.add(35);
    quick.add(65);
    quick.add(25);
    quick.add(95);
    quick.add(85);
    quick.add(75);
    quick.add(2); /*issue with 2, less than 20 throw exception*/

    Node node = quick.head;
    while (node.next != null)
        node = node.next;
    quick.print(quick.head);
    sort(quick.head, node);
    quick.print(quick.head);
}

public static void sort(Node low, Node high){
    if(low==high)
        return;

        Node prePivot = partition(low,high);
        sort(low,prePivot);
        if(low != null && prePivot==low){
            sort(prePivot.next,high);
        }else if(prePivot != null && prePivot.next != null){
            sort(prePivot.next.next, high);
        }
}

public static Node partition(Node low, Node high){

    if(low == high || low == null || high == null)
        return low;

    Node prePivot = low;
    Node current = low;
    Node pivot = high;

    while(low != high) {
        if (low.data < pivot.data) {
            prePivot = current;
            int temp = current.data;
            current.data = low.data;
            low.data = temp;
            current = current.next;
        }
        low = low.next;
    }

    int temp = current.data;
    current.data = pivot.data;
    pivot.data = temp;
    return prePivot;
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at geeksforgeek.examples.sorting.SinglyLinkedList.partition(SinglyLinkedList.java:86)
    at geeksforgeek.examples.sorting.SinglyLinkedList.sort(SinglyLinkedList.java:67)
    at geeksforgeek.examples.sorting.SinglyLinkedList.sort(SinglyLinkedList.java:72)
    at geeksforgeek.examples.sorting.SinglyLinkedList.sort(SinglyLinkedList.java:68)
    at geeksforgeek.examples.sorting.SinglyLinkedList.sort(SinglyLinkedList.java:70)
    at geeksforgeek.examples.sorting.SinglyLinkedList.main(SinglyLinkedList.java:59)

Comment: ```while(low != high) {
        if (low.data < pivot.data) {
            prePivot = current;
            int temp = current.data;
            current.data = low.data;
            low.data = temp;
            current = current.next;
        }
        low = low.next;
    }```

Last line in while loop might end up in low being null when there is no next element in the LinkedList. Have a null check there.

Comment: But it is working for input if last input is more than 20 instead of 2. It should fail for all inputs if that is the case. From stacktrace I can figure out the issue in code but why their is varying result for different inputs.